# My setOnItemClickListener from a list doesn't works

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a list View with Diferents items. I can load the list with these Items but when I try to use the  setOnItemClickListener method, it doesn't works. Its like I press some other where at the pant, how the method didn't exist. 
This is my method and it is at the end of my Oncreate:

---

```
Mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String nam=((filmsitems)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getName();
                Intent i = new Intent(this, film_information.class);
        i.putExtra("name", nam);

        startActivity(i);
            }

        });
```

---

What it's wrong in my cod? I need to do something else?
Thanks for your help

I add my Oncreate and the log

---

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_film_list);
    pdia = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pdia.setMessage("Cargando centros...");
    pdia.setCancelable(false);
    pdia.show();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    name= bundle.getString("name");


    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listfilm);
    lista.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    loadItems();

    Mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int     position, long id) {
                String nam=((filmsitems)parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getName();
                Intent i = new Intent(this, film_information.class);
        i.putExtra("name", nam);

        startActivity(i);
            }

        });



}
```

---

the log

---

```
      06-04 10:26:20.109    6000-6000/com.example.kohario.newofersalud        D/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot  TouchDown(Absolute) DOWN (314 , 221)
```

---

I add my xml files:

List

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
   android:background="@drawable/ex_fondo_degradado"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/listfilm"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
       android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listaVacia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sinConexion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Se ha producido un error. Revise su conexión a   internet y vuelva a intentarlo.\n\nSi el problema persiste podría tratarse de un problema temporal interno, en cuyo caso le rogamos que lo intente más tarde.\n\nReintentar"
        android:textColor="@color/grisOferSalud"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icono_refresh"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SinDatos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="No se han encontrado centros con los filtros indicados. Por favor, cambie sus preferencias de búsqueda e inténtelo de nuevo.\n\nAtrás"
        android:textColor="@color/grisOferSalud"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/atras"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="atras"
        android:src="@drawable/icono_atras"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

item:

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/base_fila"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/azulOferSalud"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconoLista"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_place" />
   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nombre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/verdeOferSaludTrans"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Elemento x"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.WindowTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/blanco"
        android:textSize="26sp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/blanco"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:text="Ver Información y tarifas"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/masinfo"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.WindowTitle"
            android:textColor="@color/blanco"
            android:background="@color/accent_material_dark"/>


        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the logs of what happens when you tap on the list, does it crash?

Comment: do you have only one list in the view? are you sure "Mylist" is exactly the one you are trying to select ..or  you have something else with similar name in the xml? You should add more code.. all the code of the oncreate could help

Comment: and also check what you get in String nam

Comment: Is the code in fragment??

Comment: I think problem is on your xml file. Please post it and we will have a better look

Comment: Is `Mylist`a listview? At where you have initialize it?

Comment: Yes, is initialize like private bofore the oncreate.No, is in an Activity. In theory, nam is the name of the film, from the class filmitem. I dont know if pick the correct name because never enter in this method. Yes, I have only one list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If any row item of list contains `focusable` or `clickable` view then `OnItemClickListener` won't work.**

The row item must have a param like  `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`.

It's a good option to put the listener in your adapter `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

Comment: Hi, when making tag wiki edits, please don't copy-paste articles from the internet. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something [useful to this community *specifically*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/), and be sure to attribute the original author. Thanks!